# How to generate jar file with no main method?

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse to write my program. I have 9 classes and I'm using applet and there is no main method within my codes.

I have been told that I need to submit a "runnable Jar Archive including source code". 
Somehow when I try to export my program using the Eclipse export "Runnable Jar File", I cannot find the launch configuration of my program. It works perfectly fine within Eclipse but I just can't export a runnable Jar File.

Can someone tell me what is the problem please?

Kenny

Answer (score 1):

The 'Launch Configuration' is just fancy language for a class with a main method - based on what you select the wizard will populate your runnable jar manifest with the following attribute:

```
Main-Class: example.MainClass
```

Of course, you can't actually have an executable jar without this entry. So to answer your question, you have to create a  class with a main method in it. The logic in the main method should launch your GUI in standalone mode. Then run your 'Export Runnable JAR` wizard again and choose the class you created as the Launch Configuration.

Comment: so do u mean that I have to have a main(String[] args) to create an executable jar?

Comment: Yes, you need at least one class with a `main` method in it, to create an executable JAR.

Comment: So.. this is the problem.. I have already written everything in Eclipse and I dunno where to add the main method to call the other classes.. I am quite new to Java.. n I'm not sure how to do so..

Comment: Its not necessarily a small task. Here, read [this link](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/swing/apps.html) which describes how to run an Applet as a standalone application.

Comment: I have typed the codes given in the website.. but the part with JApplet applet = new AppletClass(); what should I type for the AppletClass?? it is underlined in Eclipse..

Comment: Replace that with whatever your actual applet class is.

Comment: I have tried to write the codes in a separate class or the same as the applet class.. I have also tried to export the jar file and add the line "Main-Class: Packagename.Classname" for both cases.. it still doesn't work.. when I double click the jar file nothing come up at all..

Comment: Do u mind if I can send you my program and help me have a look what is the problem?

Comment: Its better if you post another question, actually. Try and include specific information in it to get a good response.

Comment: You may need to run your main class at least once in Eclipse, in order for it to show up under 'Launch Configurations'.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you meet some problem launching your jar

you can build your custom launcher by click 'Run configurations' , where put your jar in classpath

[image: new confiureation]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know an executable JAR needs a main method. In the manifest Main-Class tag only a class can be declared (no method) where the the main-class is located. Maybe the following code is a possible solution for you:

```
package CaesarCodePackage;


public class StartClass {


 public static void main(String [] args)
  {
     // create an object of type appletclass 
     AppletClass theApplet = new AppletClass();
     theApplet.init();   // invoke the applet's init() method
     theApplet.start();  // starts the applet

     // If the applet views something (this is optional)
     // Create a window (JFrame) and make applet the content pane.
      javax.swing.JFrame window = new javax.swing.JFrame("Caesar's Cipher");
      window.setContentPane(theApplet);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.pack();              // Arrange the components.
      window.setVisible(true);    // Make the window visible.
    }
}
```

If you do not need a Frame for showing the applet only start it.

(Thanks to Haider M. al-Khateeb for the code)

Comment: what should I write for the CaesarCode?

Comment: Replace CeaserCode with your appletclass that provides the method init() and start(). Applets have to provide this 2 method as entry point. Maybe you can provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting the project as a JAR (Not runnable JAR).

I think ti will then let you specify your own MANIFEST file. With this you simply need to make sure the MANIFEST.mf file contains a MAIN-Class for the program. (You will need a main class for the JAR to run)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

e.g.

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

Comment: I have tried exporting "Jar File" in Eclipse and I can extract the file and there is a META-INF folder with a MANIFEST.MF text file. Do you mean this file?

Comment: Yes, I think it is generated automatically but you should be able to override it by creating it in your project, you can use this generated one as a starting point.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a main.. and I don't know how to add a main because I'm using an applet..