# If I'm using applet how can I create a .jar file using Eclipse?

Tags: java, jar, applet, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I am currently working on creating an artificial world and I have followed the following website
http://www.ethics.ubc.ca/eame/eameweb/Simulators/JavaProject/TofC.html

He used an applet to create it and have 9 classes in total.

I have done edited the coding and it works perfectly fine in Eclipse but when I try to export a .jar file its just not working.

I have tried to export it as a "Jar File" and generate a Bug.jar and I extract the file and add, in the MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Main-Class: Bugs.World
```

Then when I double click the Bug.jar file, nothing happen.

When I try to export with "Runnable Jar File", I can't find my program under the Launch Configuration.

Can anyone help me on this please? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.ethics.ubc.ca/eame/eameweb/Simulators/JavaProject/TofC.html is a 404 here.  (Not that the URL seems that relevant to the question.)

Comment: Did you create a class with a main method like I asked you to do [on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506704/how-to-generate-jar-file-with-no-main-method)?

Answer (score 1):

> Then when I double click the Bug.jar file, nothing happen.

That won't work for an applet.  For more info., run it from the CLI as:

```
java -jar Bug.jar
```

---

To launch an applet, it needs to be embedded in HTML or launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (embedded or free floating) using a JNLP.

Comment: If I really need to create a Jar archive what should I do?

Comment: A Jar file can be embedded in HTML or launched using JWS.  Almost everything that is deployed should be in a Jar.

Comment: See also @AndrewThompson's _tag-in-source_ technique using `appletviewer`, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455045/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455066/230513).