# Not able to create runnable jar file of my BDD maven project having no main class

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, pom.xml

I have done a lot of research to make a runnable jar file for my project which is BDD-maven project with no main class. I found links where it explains if there is a main class but to make a runnable jar file without any main class i didnt come across. Is there anyway I can make runnable jar file?
Thanks
Ref

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506704/how-to-generate-jar-file-with-no-main-method

Comment: How can you have a runnable jar with no main class!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate jar file with no main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506704/how-to-generate-jar-file-with-no-main-method)